# proving $W_1 + W_2$ is a subspace of V

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-verification

I'm just trying to clarify one of my answers here.

Here is the question:

if $W_1$ and $W_2$ are subspaces of a vector Space $V$, show that $W_1 + W_2 = \{x+y : x \in W_1,  y \in W_2\}$   is a subspace of V.

To prove this is closed under vector addition, I did the following:

Let $x_1$ and $x_2 \in W_1$ and $y_1$ and $y_2 \in W_2$.

we must show that $(x_1+y_1) + (x_2+y_2) \in W_1 + W_2$

rewrite as $(x_1+x_2) + (y_1 + y_2) \in W_1 + W_2$.

we know $(x_1+x_2)$ is a vector in $W_1$ because $W_1$ is a subspace.

Same for $W_2$.

does this prove that the subset is closed under vector addition? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep! Your proof is fine. You'll now have to show that $W_1 + W_2$  is closed under scalar multiplication as well.

Comment: thanks, I will do this in a similar way :)

Comment: Here's a neat trick: to show that a set $W$ containing the zero-vector is a subspace, it's enough to prove that $x + ky$ is a member of $W$ for any $x,y\in W$ and any scalar $k$.  Why?  Setting $k = 1$ gives you closure under addition, and setting $x = \vec 0$ gives you closure under scalar multiplication. This often makes for a quicker proof.